# how to query a sub report in crystal report?

Tags: vb.net

i got a multiple table and i think subreport is the only way to get my report that i wanted and after i made some test of subreports..the subreports appears no data..how to query the subreports ???

```
 Dim ad As New SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * From Studz_Table WHERE id = '" & Board.ListView1.SelectedItems.Item(0).Text & "'", conn)
    Dim ds As New DataSet
    ad.Fill(ds, "Studz_Table")
    Dim rpt As New Studz_infoCR
    rpt.SetDataSource(ds)
    CrystalReportViewer1.Refresh()
    CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = rpt
```

my main table is called studz_table and i want to get some data in my other table..

Answer (score 1):

If I understood correctly, you want to add data to the subreport.
You could try:

```
rap.Subreports("SubReportName.rpt").SetDataSource (SubRapDs)
```

And don’t forget to  link the report to the subreport. Right click the subreport -> change subreport links